How databricks access cross account resources using unity catalog?
I have recently started to work on databricks. This is how our setup looks like.

Depending on this I wanted to clear few things

How workspace in one aws account access the catalog data in another aws account?
What is the role of metastore here if this doesn't have a storage?
What exactly is metastore in terms of resource? Where exactly it resides? Is my interpretation correct?

I have tried searching online in the documentation but couldn't really find any concrete info in regards to this question.
Thanks in advance.
